# How to display QPointF stored in a QList?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qlist

```
QList <QPointF> markers;
markers.append (QPointF (getLat (), getLon ()));


QList <QPointF> :: iterator i;
for (i = markers.begin(); i != markers.end(); ++i)
     std :: cout << *i << endl;
```

Gives me:

> error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << i.QList::iterator::operator* with T = QPointF'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`qDebug()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdebug.html).

```
QList<QPointF> markers;
markers.append(getLat(), getLon());
QList<QPointF>::iterator i;
for (i = markers.begin(); i != markers.end(); ++i)
    qDebug() << *i;
```

Remember to include `QDebug`:

```
#include <QDebug>
```

Answer (score 2):

A foreach loop would be simplier for that:

```
Q_FOREACH( QPointF p, markers ) {
    qDebug() << p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `QPointF` class by itself does not have a `<<` overload operator. You can either re-implement it and overload the operator yourself or more simply just try to output the coordinates `myPoint.x()` and `myPoint.y()`.